Do crystals of the same structure display identical anisotropy?
For example, the hardness of diamonds is 97 GPa in <100> face, and 162 GPa in <111> face, which means <111> face is 67% harder than <100>. Is this ratio the same for all crystals of diamond structure, such as silicon, cubic boron nitride (cBN), and cubic SiC? I mean, while hardness is dependent on the bond length and bond strength, dimensionless parameters should remain the same.

Properties such as hardness are also strongly affected by crystal defects.
